# How to use PC webcam for AR Foundation in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios-simulator, arkit, arcore, game-development

I am currently working on a project that has AR stuff in it, so before I start I've decided to use ARFoundation. Now when my project is done I have to test it, but unfortunately my phone does not support ARKit. So I decided to test it directly in Unity, using its play mode, but when I run it the "Game" panel gets black and I see nothing. I think it is because the webcam is not turning on. So how can I turn on my webcam in Unity in order to test my ARFoundation app?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't just downvote it but tell them how to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the webcam. It is simply because `ARFoundation` need ARCore (android) / ARKit (ios) compatible device.

> Requirement Hardware
>
> 1. ARKit compatible device that is also supported by ARCore.
> 2. A USB cable to connect your device to your development machine.
>
> Source: [Quickstart for ARCore Extensions for
>   iOS](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity-arf/quickstart-ios)

The one with play test using `Unity` editor is [Vuforia](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/getting-started-with-vuforia-in-unity.html). Furthermore it support most modern devices.

> Vuforia Engine provides a simulator mode in the Game view that you can activate by pressing the Play button. You can use this feature to evaluate and rapidly prototype your scene(s) without having to deploy to a device.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that, I and my teem cannot use Vuforia because of its policy. It is a big project, which has to be posted in App Store and Google Play, or be commercialized. And in the Vuforia FAQ it is written that for the commercialized projects it is forbidden using the open-source version. So because it is a low budget and no success-ensured startup we cannot rely only on the budget gained from downloading rate. If there was no such rule of course I would use Vuforia instead of ARFoundation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at EasyAR? I have used it for a couple of low budget projects and it's pretty good for a free product. Use v3 for no watermark or v4 (Sense) if you are ok with a watermark. You can pay/subscribe to go watermark free on v4.